# play Video in VideoView

Tags: android, video

In my activity I am trying to play a video which is stored in raw folder. below is my activity.
In the first button I am not getting error also like can't play this video, but only black screen appears. while clicking the second button I am getting a message that can't play this video. below is my activity

```
package com.example.college;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class FirstYear extends Activity {
Button cse,it,ece,eee;
VideoView vv;
MediaController mc;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.first_year);

cse=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
it=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
ece=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
eee=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);

vv=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
mc=new MediaController(this);
mc.setAnchorView(vv);

cse.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        vv.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.college/"+R.raw.c));
        vv.start();

    }
});

it.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        vv.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.college/"+R.raw.k));
        vv.start();

    }
});

ece.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        vv.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.college/"+R.raw.a));
        vv.start();

    }
});

eee.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        vv.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.college/"+R.raw.s));
        vv.start();

    }
});


 }
 }
```

Comment: Is your video ends with .mp4 in raw folder(like k.mp4,s.mp4,etc)

Comment: can't play this video two reasons are there. 1.out of buffer memory issue 2.file type doesn't support.

Comment: my video format mp4 only. and it is in raw folder only.

Comment: 07-18 10:25:45.070: E/MediaPlayer(17860): error (1, -2147483648)
07-18 10:25:45.074: E/MediaPlayer(17860): Error (1,-2147483648)
07-18 10:25:45.078: D/VideoView(17860): Error: 1,-2147483648

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is correct. All the errors are related to video resolution.
I have replaced video with different resolution , and it is working